# Reading from a file Haskell

Tags: haskell

Read from file those lines and make a list like this

```
 2010‐04‐16,130.68,132.17,130.25,130.63,9546200,130.63
 2010‐04‐15,130.53,131.14,130.19,130.89,6425300,130.89   

List [ "2010‐04‐16","130.68,132.17","130.25","130.63","9546200","130.63"]
```

how i can make this with take predicate ? or any other predicates

Comment: yes but how to determine them with comma ?

Comment: The question I referred to has comma as the example...

Comment: @user760157 Did you look at my answer? Was it helpful or do you need more clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do something like this using `Data.List` API:

```
import Data.List

split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split delim = map (dropWhile (== delim)) . groupBy (\_ c -> c /= delim)
```

The output with one of your input strings will be:

```
Prelude Data.List> split ',' "20100416,130.68,132.17,130.25,130.63,9546200,130.63"
["20100416","130.68","132.17","130.25","130.63","9546200","130.63"]
```

HTH...

Comment: You meant `split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]`, right?